# C# - Automatic creation of objects with config list/file

Tags: c#, oop, model

My intention is to create a bunch of objects of a class `City` at the launch of the application by using a config file.

The class `City` has some properties like `CityName`, `Population` etc.

Basically the config file delivers a `List<string>` with all city names like the following:

```
public List<string> configCityNames = new List<string> {
    "New York", "Chicago", "Boston", "San Francisco", "Miami", "etc."
};
```

Also I want to store all `City` objects in a repository to easily access them from somewhere else.

How can I automatically create one `City` object for each of the config `List` items? Maybe with a loop in an init function of the model? For me is especially unclear how to handle the object/variable names? When all objects are created in a loop, won't they have all the same object/variable name?

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish this task.  What have you tried?

Comment: Same variable name?  Kind of.  What you will end up with is a `List<City>` object.  Each item in the list is a new city class with the properties defined.  To reference the city you want you might do something like `var myCity = cities.Where(c => c.CityName == "Boston")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define an extension method to generate a List of `City` from a List of `string`

```
public class City
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Population { get; set; }
}

public static class Mappings
{
    public static List<City> ConvertToCity(this List<string> names)
    {
        List<City> cities = new List<City>();

        foreach (string name in names)
        {
            cities.Add(new City { Name = name });
        }
        return cities;
    }
}
```

You can then use the extension method as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<string> configCityNames = new List<string> {
            "New York", "Chicago", "Boston", "San Francisco", "Miami", "etc."
        };

        List<City> cities = configCityNames.ConvertToCity();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why create extension methods when the Framework already has LINQ methods `.Select`, `.ToList` and `.ToDictionary` that can accomplish tasks like this without writing any extra code?

Comment: Sure, you could use `configCityNames.Select(x => new City { Name = x });` instead. I just wanted to provide an alternative for those who are not familiar with LINQ and that includes me :)

Comment: @IanMercer: Can you please provide a detailed answer with code as I am also not familiar with LINQ methods?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this I have often used a dictionary to keep track of the values while knowing a Key (as long as the key is unique - if it is not unique you could use a list of KeyValuePairs)

For example, I would use the city name as a key to the dictionary and create an instance of the City class and set the variables. It will allow you to loop through them since the Dictionary values are IEnumerable but still allow you to find the city by name if needed.

```
class City
{
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public int Population { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    public static List<string> configCityNames = new List<string> 
    {
        "New York", "Chicago", "Boston", "San Francisco", "Miami", "etc."
    };


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cities = new Dictionary<string, City>();
        foreach(var cityName in configCityNames)
            cities.Add(cityName, new City() { CityName = cityName });

        foreach (var city in cities.Values)
            Console.WriteLine(city.CityName);
    }
}
```